# Can I run an .exe on the host PC from Android, when connected via USB on debug mode?

Tags: android

I have an android service that checks an url for information. It already works fine. I'm running it on debug (development) mode, and I'm able to send commands to Android by the "adb shell".

Now, I wanted to know if it is possible to send commands on the other direction: From android to PC. Can I call an .exe, or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ssh to send a command to the PC.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to create (on topic) or find (off topic) software for both the Android device and the PC in order to support this.  Probably you'll end up with a TCP or unix socket forward from the PC to the android and a connection from that direction which you maintain open, and then send commands back through that to be processed and executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Chris Stratton, I ended up creating a PC listener for a TCP port, that fires the .exe program when requested. Then, on Android, I'm making the sending the TCP call.